# Can't update document with version in cmis

Tags: java, alfresco, cmis

I am trying to update a document (with version support) in **cmis-alfresco**. Normal document update successfully. But when I tried to update a document that have a `relation`, its getting a error.

```
            newFileProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
            newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,
                    "D:cmiscustom:document");
            newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "ADGFileSource1");
            Document sourceDoc = folderAssociations.createDocument(
                    newFileProps, null, VersioningState.MAJOR);

            newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "cmis:document");
            newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "ADGFileTarget1");
            newFileProps.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID,
                    "D:cmiscustom:document");
            Document targetDoc = folderAssociations.createDocument(
                    newFileProps, null, VersioningState.MAJOR);


            Map<String, String> relProps = new HashMap<String, String>();
            relProps.put("cmis:sourceId", sourceDoc.getId());
            relProps.put("cmis:targetId", targetDoc.getId());
            relProps.put("cmis:objectTypeId", "R:cmiscustom:assoc");
            ObjectId relId = session.createRelationship(relProps, null,
                    null, null);


             if (sourceDoc.getAllowableActions().getAllowableActions().contains(org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.Action.CAN_CHECK_OUT)) {
                 sourceDoc.refresh();
                String testName = sourceDoc.getContentStream().getFileName();
                ObjectId idOfCheckedOutDocument = sourceDoc.checkOut();
                Document pwc = (Document) session.getObject(idOfCheckedOutDocument);

                String docText = "This is a sample document with an UPDATE";
                byte[] content = docText.getBytes();

                ByteArrayInputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content);         
                String filename=sourceDoc.getName();
                ContentStream contentStream = session.getObjectFactory().createContentStream(filename, Long.valueOf(content.length), "text/plain", stream);          
                ObjectId objectId = pwc.checkIn(false, null, contentStream, "just a minor change");
             }
```

error:

```
Constraint violation: 00190010 Found 1 integrity violations:
The association source multiplicity has been violated:
```

Comment: Can you specify what kind of relationship R:cmiscustom:assoc is?

Comment: @TahirMalik : ya. iam using R:cmiscustom:assoc relation.

Comment: I'm asking you to specify. Is it a child-parent relationship or a peer-peer one?

Comment: Could this be associated with the definition of cmiscustom:assoc `         <associations>
        <association name="cmiscustom:assoc">
               <source>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>false</many>
               </source>
               <target>
                  <class>cm:content</class>
                  <mandatory>false</mandatory>
                  <many>true</many>
               </target>
        </association>
</associations>` which has source many equals false and when you have two versions of a document you have two sources?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and was fairly desperate as it used to worked prior to Alfresco 5.x. Also updating the chemistry and import org.alfresco.cmis.client.AlfrescoDocument packages did not help.

But I found the following workaround. Our Alfresco installation had always been configured to auto-version, so I went around the checkout/update/checkin procedure by simply setting a new content to the document:

```
theDoc.setContentStream(contentStream, true);
```

Be aware, that this will add a new version in our configuration and thus "theDoc" points to an old version of the document from now on. Therefore, you maybe need to fetch the document again to have it point to the latest version to avoid "Document is not the latest version" error.